# Angular 2.0.0-beta.15 & webpack: "Cannot find the name 'require'."

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have recently upgraded my webpack-based Angular 2 app from 2.0.0-beta.2 to 2.0.0-beta.15. I received a lot of errors on compiling, a lot of which were resolved by adding the line:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

to my bootstrap file. However, I am still receiving a lot of errors pertaining to `require`:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

The TypeScript loader is using version 1.8.10 of the compiler, and my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./app/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

What else do I need to do to get this working? This is a *real* blocker for me!

Comment: How are you using require? `import myModule = require('myModule')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a tool such as [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings/) to add type definitions for your modules.

Install it globally:

```
npm i -g typings
```

Create a config for it:

```
typings init
```

There's a type definition for using require.

```
typings install require --ambient --save
```

Be aware that typings will add type definitions for main and for the browser, make a change on your tsconfig.json file to only include the browser version.

```
"filesGlob": [
    "./app/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "!./typings/main",
    "!./typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm liking the look of this solution. Do I now have to reference one of these .ts files in my app .ts files? If so, why is that a change from the previous version? Never had to do that before.

Comment: That fixed one problem, thanks; but now I have something unrelated.

Comment: If you use Typescript 2.x: use `npm install --save-dev @types/node` or `npm install --save-dev @types/requirejs` instead of installing typings module

Answer (score 3):

Create definition file like `declarations.d.ts` with content:

```
//fix error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require':
declare function require(string:string):any;
```

and add reference to `main.ts`/`boot.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/declarations.d.ts" />
```